# "No forwarding for this Domain" - How do I resolve this?

Tags: redirect, dns, forwarding

I've got the following showing up on the website [dreiwellen.org](http://dreiwellen.org) that is hosted on my rootserver:

[image: No forwarding for this Domain - image]

It must be the default for a special case or something, I just cannot figure it out... Never saw this before! I wasn't able to find any information on that subject online, not even close.

This messege is shown since about yesterday (cannot pinpoint the exact time). The page is online now for about 6 months and was fine till yesterday!
For some people it's showing this image, others see the page as it should be displayed. As for myself: my desktop computer only gives me the picture, my cell phone (a Nexus 4) has no problems displaying the page.
Both share the internet connection (desktop on cable, cell phone via w-lan; both using the same router).

This page is hosted on a shared ip-address along with [michael-brecker.com](http://michael-brecker.com) (which displays just fine!).
Whatever connection test I tried (ping, tracert, 301 redirect test, Chrome's internal domain test, ...) seemed to be okay. This page / domain is reachable with both IPv4 & IPv6...

So my guess is
a) it's some kind of local issue (on the client computer)
b) it's an issue with the provider the domain was bought /rented from, becaus I get the same strange behaviour when trying to open[redirect.checkdomain.de](http://redirect.checkdomain.de/) and cannot locate the image file under the given filepath on my server!

Which is it?! Or is it a totally different issue?!
Let me know if you need any additional information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's gone. I switched to another root server (same company, just a different model / different hardware) and it just works again.

So my guess would be the IP-address of the old server (no idea why that would be, though). Trace route stopped at the hop right before the old root server (so the redirect / DNS entry of the domain didn't work properly I guess) and that's not the case any more.